# Process Builder: Criteria for Member Deleted from Campaign

Tags: process-builder, campaign, campaign-member

From within Process Builder, I would like to setup a criteria such that every time I delete a contact from a campaign, it would kick off an action.

To detect deleting a contact, I have setup the following condition to evaluate as true:  **[CampaignMember].IsDeleted**

However, for some reason, every time I manually delete a member from a campaign, the criteria would not trigger.  Here is my setup:

[image]

Is there a way to setup Process Builder to detect if a member has been deleted from a campaign?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Process builder doesn't allow you to check for deleted items. It only supports creation and editing. I did find a work around this, however. If you create a new roll up summary field in the campaign object you can count the number of campaign members. Then you can create a process in process builder that will do an action if the prior value of the count of campaign members is lower than the current value of the count. The formula would look something like this:

```
IF(PRIORVALUE(*campaignMemberCount*) > *campaignMemberCount*, TRUE, FALSE) == TRUE
```

I found this [link](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000korHAAQ) that helped me test your problem.

Comment: This would be done by creating a process on the change of a campaign instead of an individual campaign member.

Comment: You know you could just say `PRIORVALUE(*campaignMemberCount*) > *campaignMemberCount*`... also, you can **[edit]** your own answer if you want to add additional information.